# Is there an R function for importing a specific portion of a JSON file?

Tags: r, json, parsing, geojson, zipcode

RStudio will not load my entire geoJSON file without slowing my computer down. The file contains the precise coordinates needed to draw US zip-code shapes. The entire file is large. I would like to import all the coordinates for one zip-code at a time. The geoJSON file contains properties called GEOID10 and ZCTA5CE10 that correspond with a specific zipcode. Here is a portion of this file:

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "name": "cb_2017_us_zcta510_500k",
 "crs": {
   "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269"
     }
   },
   "features": [
      {
       "type": "Feature",
       "properties": {
       "ZCTA5CE10": "35442",
       "AFFGEOID10": "8600000US35442",
       "GEOID10": "35442",
       "ALAND10": 610213891,
       "AWATER10": 10838694
   },
   "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            [
              -88.252618,
               32.92675
            ],
            [
              -88.249724,
               32.93242
            ],
```

The file continues with many more coordinates. The structure is the same for every zip-code in the US. I have been looking into packages such as jsonlite. However, I have limited programming experience. So far, I have written this line of code which would import the entire file into R:

```
zipcodes <- geojson_read("zipcodes.geojson", what = "sp")
```

This line freezes my computer. R will upload the entire file on a larger computer, however I would like the code to work on a normal computer. Is there a better way to do this? Can I designate R to upload just the data corresponding to "GEOID10": "35442"? Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think `jsonlite` or `RJSONIO` have subset-at-read functionality. You might be able to rig a call to `jq` (external program) to subset it before you try to bring it into R. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: you could try `library(geojsonsf)` to read in the geojson, it's more efficient that `geojsonio` and `sf` - related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52901234/5977215

Comment: maybe using `sqldf` with a *PostgreSQL* driver, as *PostgreSQL* has this feature

Comment: There's an R client for `jq` if you want to try jq from R https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/jqr/ - however, if the file is big enough you may have to do jq on the command line

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, wouldn't using `sqldf` with a pg-backend still need to load the entire struct into memory before passing it to pg? (I *was* just reading about pg's json support this weekend...)

Comment: @SymbolixAU geojsonsf and sf worked well! I was able to load the file! Thank you. Next, I would like to still parse the data into the individual zip-codes. This time within R after loading the entire file.

Comment: @r2evans honestly I have no idea, I was just sharing my thoughts as I thought it might help, but I've never done anything like that.

Comment: I'm confused about why this question and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55446775/5325862) were both posted today when they're nearly identical. Just like with the other question, the amount of JSON included here is too small to be valid JSON on its own (no closing brackets). There are datasets included with GeoJSON-related packages that would make a reproducible example possible

Comment: @camille The other question is actually about how to subset a data.frame, and not related to the GeoJSON in any way.